# Do all 20x http responses have a body, and all non-20x http responses have no body?

Tags: html, rest, http

Is there a list that makes it clear that a request must or is not possible to have a body?

I've read some documeatation like [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success), and they introduce the meaning of every http status code well. But I can't figure out whether the response is supposed to have body. Inferring from the introduction does not satisfy me, I hope that there is a offical documentation statement it clearly.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That list does mention "204 No Content"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, all (final) HTTP response messages can have a body (with the known exceptions of 204, 205 and 304).

Comment: Doesn't `205` typically also not have a body?

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: thanks for your answer, is it from a offical documentation or from your experience?

Comment: @goushiso Julian is one of the authors of the HTTP specification